# How to set probability for randomly picking character from a string in r

Tags: r, random, character

i have a string with repetition of 4 character "atgc"

```
a <- "attgctagctagtcatgctagctacgtacgcatcgtacgatgcatatgctttttaattt"
```

how to randomly pick a string a size 5 in which the probability of "gc" in that should be 60%

Comment: do you want to randomly pick a 5 char string with exactly 3 g's or c's?

Comment: Actual string is some 3gb file. From that i want to randomly pick 280 character which has 60% "GC" in it.. 60% "GC" means 60% of 280 not total 3 gb file

Comment: As an example, for a substring of `nchar` 10, you want 3 _pairs_ of "GC" or 6 characters of "G" and/or "C" in it?

Comment: @alexis_laz my question doesnot depend on char . whatsoever is the length of nchar i want all possible combination of string of 5 character which has 60% of G and C in it

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's one way:

```
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
all.str <- sapply(1:(nchar(a)-4),function(i) substr(a,i,i+4))
gc      <- grepl("gc",all.str)
indx    <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),10,p=c(0.6,0.4),replace=TRUE)
result  <- c(sample(all.str[gc],sum(indx)),sample(all.str[!gc],sum(!indx)))
result  <-result[sample(seq_along(result),length(result))]
result
#  [1] "cgatg" "ctagc" "cgtac" "tagct" "gtacg" "ttaat" "catat" "cgcat" "acgca" "atgct"
```

So there are two categories of 5 base segments: those that have "gc", and those that don't. `all.str` is a vector of all the 5 base segments. `gc` is a vector of the same length as `all.str` indicating whether a particular element has "gc" or not. `indx` is a random vector of length 10 (could be any length) which has T or F where T appears with probability 0.6 (note this does mean exactly 0.6, just that the probability is 0.6 of having T).

So we grab a random sample of 5-base segments from `all.str[gc]` and a second random sample from `all.str[!gc]`, combine these, and randomize the order of the result.

More generally, this is an example of stratified or proportional sampling. There are packages in R for this, and I'm sure someone will show you how to do this using one of those packages.

Finally, I have a feeling that your real string `a` is a lot longer than the example, so this might not scale all that well.